# How to fix fprintf vulnerability?

Tags: c++, c, printf

In my code I used fprintf. I used flawfinder to check the code for vulnerabilities and I got that:

> 358:  [4] (format) `fprintf`:   If format strings can be influenced by
>   an attacker, they can be   exploited. Use a constant for the format
>   specification.

Can someone explain to me what **Use a constant for the format specification** actually means? Is there any safe version of `fprintf`?

Comment: Certain this occurred because code had a `fprintf(outf, non_constant_string, ...)` rather than `fprintf(outf, "some constant string", ...)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `fprintf` determines how many arguments it should get by examining the format string. If the format string doesn't agree with the actual arguments, you have undefined behavior which can manifest as a security vulnerability.

The problem is particularly bad if the string supplied can be influenced by the user of your program, because he can then specifically design the string to make your program do bad things.

There is no safe version of `fprintf` in the C standard. C++ streams avoid the problem, at the cost of not having format strings and using a far more verbose syntax for specifying formatting options.

Comment: Only slightly more verbose when used correctly, and far more flexible and structured.

Comment: @JamesKanze: They are flexible... unless you want to translate your program. Consider this: `fprintf(_"(John took %d apples"), 5)` vs this: `cout << _("John took ") << 5 << _(" apples")`.

Answer (score 6):

A constant string, as in a string literal.

Like in

```
fprintf(someFile, "%s", someStringVariable);
```

and ***not*** like

```
fprintf(someFile, someStringVariable);
```

Answer (score 3):

It means it wants you to write:

```
fprintf(out, "foo %s", some_string);
```

instead of what you have, which I guess is something like:

```
const char *format = "foo %s";

/* some time later */

fprintf(out, format, some_string);
```

The reason is that it's worried `format` might come from user input or something, and a malicious user could supply a format `foo %s%s%s` in order to provoke undefined behavior that they may be able to exploit.

Obviously if you're choosing between `n` different format strings, all of which are string literals in your code and all use the same format specifiers, but you choose which one at runtime, then following this advice is a bit awkward and wouldn't make your code any safer. But you could have `n` functions instead of `n` strings, and each function calls `fprintf` with a different string literal.

If you're reading the format string out of a config file (which is one fairly crude way of implementing internationalization from scratch) then you're basically out of luck. The linter doesn't trust your translator to use the right format codes for the arguments supplied to the call. And arguably neither should you :-)

Comment: In a lot of cases, the string will come out of a locale specific message file.  (I think that GNU's version of `gettext` will verify that the format specifiers are identical, but otherwise, you're stuck.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: funny, I was just writing the same thing. Yes, `printf` is tempting to use for i18n and certainly a lot closer to solving the whole problem for you than iostream formatting is. But if you're worried about this kind of error then it just falls short.

Comment: I'm not sure that `printf` is better for I18n; it really depends on the type of text you're trying to translate.  (To get really fluent, arbitrary sentences, you need a separate DLL for each language.  For simple error messages, `std::ostream` is at least as good as `printf`, and a lot easier to use.)

Comment: @James: a typical i18n example (that requires formatting: fixed messages of course don't) is similar to mail merge. You want to translate a sentence like "Thank you <Customer name>, your order for <count> x <item name> will be delivered by <date>". This can easily be configured as a single string containing printf format codes, for iostream it would have to be several separate parts. Issues of word order are dealt with by a Posix extension to `printf` and rather awkward using streams. Depending on the translator, though, formats in translated text might just be a non-starter.

Comment: However, I have cunningly avoided phrasing the sentence to require a plural, so you're right of course that translation might require more logic than either `printf` or stream formatting is capable of delivering on its own. But for "assembling the right bits in the right order", which is often enough to cover most of the work, `printf` is easier and more effective IMO because the config files are nicer. Of course either one is adequate to write a printf-style formatter that doesn't use varargs.

Comment: The sentence which you use already causes problems.  The form of <item name> will depend on count, in a locale specific manner.  (In Russian, for example, numbers like 21, which end in 1, are followed by the singular.  Other languages have dual.)  And the form of "your" may depend on the gender of the customer (and will often depend on the number).  And so on.  There is an intermediate level where the X-Open extensions to `printf` are applicable, but it is surprisingly small.  I once implemented a Format class, which supported full X/Open `printf` formatting.  Never found much use for it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: are you saying that in Russian one would use a singluar / plural in the phrase "n x spoon" according to the value of `n`? Because of course in English it can be singular regardless of the number, one does not need to put "2 x spoons" on an invoice to mean 2 spoons (and if one did it's dangerously ambiguous). Anyway I've already mentioned that plurals add a wrinkle. The way to deal with that is usually to have singular and plural form of the noun together with a function of `n` to choose between them. I don't see how iostreams helps at all with implementing that, but YMMV.

Comment: I don't know Russian, I just know what I've read about it, so I can't say in particular.  But the use of the singular in this case is a characteristic of the Germanic languages: you'd certainly use the plural if there was more than one in French or Italian.  (For that matter, I'd use the plural here in English---but not in German.  But my English is very American; maybe it's different in England.)

Comment: Also I don't know many languages, but in what languages does the form of "your order" depend on the number of items in the order? The order is singular.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Interesting. So if you're going to write "2 x spoons" then what's the point of the `x` or multiplication character? It seems entirely redundant, you could just say "2 spoons". I'm not claiming that "2 x spoon" is particularly fluent English, mind, just that it's unambiguous and good enough for orders and invoicing. I've noticed that Amazon puts the item name in double-quotes, just so it's absolutely clear that the name is an atom that doesn't participate in the grammar of the sentence :-)

Comment: Although I would love for them to pluralize grammatically in English, let alone other languages. Then I could buy "2 x The Designs and Evolutions of C++" ;-)

Comment: The number in "your order" is the number of "you".  Many languages make the distinction thy/your, even if modern English doesn't.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ah right, I misread your comment about "your". Yes, agreed. I imagine there's less difference in a business context but in some languages it would depend on the age of the customer.

Comment: My point isn't that iostream helps here; it's just that `printf` is equally useless (at this level).  You need a separate DLL for each language, pratically.  Where iostream does help is that it doesn't embed the formatting information in the text, so it cannot accidentally get modified by the translator, and so that if you want to change it, you don't have to figure out where it is in the translated text.

Comment: Re your order: in Arabic, the form of "your" would depend on the gender as well.  (Since programs aren't too good at this, a lot of languages have "work-arounds".  In Italian, for example, I've always seen "voi" in things like invoices, output by a computer; although I can't imagine a context where it would be used in a personal letter.)

Comment: @James: true. And `printf` is the other way around, if you want to change the language-specific text you don't have to figure out where it is in the code. It's a quoted-string DSL. In practice I have worked with translators who are familiar enough with `printf` codes that they can write around them and warn you if they need different substitutions from the ones you used in English. And also translators who've never heard of %s. I think it's an overstatement to say you "need" a separate dll per language. I (well, my past employers) have delivered reasonably simple GUI apps without.

Comment: ... and yes we did native-speaker UAT, before you ask, so the results were not completely mangled. Tbh the major challenge during translation was working with the German translators to fit everything on a range of small screen sizes (we never used a word-breaking algorithm, so aside from the text being longer there was more wasted whitespace). And conversely wondering what to do with all that empty space in Chinese.